# Creating a fake SD Card on virtual box Windows 7

Tags: virtualbox

I am testing software that interacts with an SD card. I need to create fake SD cards on my Windows 7 instance to run software tests. The software under test does not respond to anything but the SD card. Does anybody know how to create fake SD Cards mounted on a virtual box instance?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On Friday I learned that this is solved in Java by using the JNA library. I have not verified this solution yet.

Comment: can you find a real fake sd card (ebay unrealistically low price for 128GB) and then use dd to copy the image ?